# Sufficient way to get Wikipedia's POTD

Tags: hyperlink, wikipedia

In this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Picture_of_the_day you can see Wikipedia:POTD and (below) Commons:POTD.

I've found this: [Wikipedia API: Cannot query Picture of the Day URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084442/wikipedia-api-cannot-query-potd-url) but it is for Commons:POTD.

Is there anything similar for Wikipedia:POTD ?

Answer (score 0):

No, I didn't see anything like that. On enwiki you can get POTD from proper template, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <expandtemplates xml:space="preserve">[[:Template:Potd/2013-12-29]]</expandtemplates>
</api>
```